# Alter table tablename CONCATENATE error via the Databricks notebook

Tags: apache-spark, hiveql, databricks

I want to schedule the Databricks notebook which merges small ORC files to one bigger ORC file on a daily basis for a particular hive table. I'm looking to implement this using Spark, but currently stuck with the error as shown below.

My databricks runtime: 6.3 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11)

Any pointers would be great.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}

val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Hive small ORC files merge").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE [TABLE_NAME] CONCATENATE")
```

Error:

```
`Operation not allowed: ALTER TABLE CONCATENATE(line 1, pos 0)

 == SQL ==ALTER TABLE CONCATENATE^^^

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.operationNotAllowed(ParserUtils.scala:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder$$anonfun$visitFailNativeCommand$1.apply(SparkSqlParser.scala:1135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder$$anonfun$visitFailNativeCommand$1.apply(SparkSqlParser.scala:1126)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder.visitFailNativeCommand(SparkSqlParser.scala:1126)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder.visitFailNativeCommand(SparkSqlParser.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$FailNativeCommandContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:831)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:18)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder$$anonfun$visitSingleStatement$1.apply(AstBuilder.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder$$anonfun$visitSingleStatement$1.apply(AstBuilder.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitSingleStatement(AstBuilder.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser$$anonfun$parsePlan$1.apply(ParseDriver.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser$$anonfun$parsePlan$1.apply(ParseDriver.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:69)
at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser$$anonfun$parsePlan$1.apply(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:64)
at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser$$anonfun$parsePlan$1.apply(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:61)
at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser.parse(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:84)
at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser.parsePlan(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:694)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:694)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:693)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:716)
at line341589a136f246f788b6b288061c96ae31.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4297307810790143:4)
at line341589a136f246f788b6b288061c96ae31.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4297307810790143:50)
at line341589a136f246f788b6b288061c96ae31.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4297307810790143:52)
at line341589a136f246f788b6b288061c96ae31.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4297307810790143:54)
at line341589a136f246f788b6b288061c96ae31.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4297307810790143:56)
at line341589a136f246f788b6b288061c96ae31.$read$$iw.<init>(command-4297307810790143:58)
at line341589a136f246f788b6b288061c96ae31.$read.<init>(command-4297307810790143:60)
at line341589a136f246f788b6b288061c96ae31.$read$.<init>(command-4297307810790143:64)
at line341589a136f246f788b6b288061c96ae31.$read$.<clinit>(command-4297307810790143)
at line341589a136f246f788b6b288061c96ae31.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
at line341589a136f246f788b6b288061c96ae31.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
at line341589a136f246f788b6b288061c96ae31.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:699)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:652)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:385)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:362)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:251)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:246)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:288)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:362)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`
```

Answer (score 2):

As per spark source code, `ALTER TABLE <> CONCATENATE` option is not implemented or not supported as of now. Please check below code for more information.

[Spark SQL Parser](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkSqlParser.scala)

[Spark Un Supported Hive Native Commands](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/73dd6cf9b558f9d752e1f3c13584344257ad7863/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4#L217)

Answer (score 0):

This command works from Hive only:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONCATENATE;
```

Does not work from Spark, yet.